# Update a varbinary(max) column from a varchar(max) column in same table

Tags: sql, t-sql, binary, base64, sql-server-2017

I have a table `volcards` which contains columns including `photo_text` [`varchar(max)`] and `photo` [`varbinary(max)`].

The application that collects the data and photo from the user is Filemaker (Claris) which then populates the SQL Server fields using ODBC. But apparently although it cannot populate a binary field in a SQL Server table, it can populate a Base64 field for the photo. The proprietary application that prints the ID cards from this data requires the SQL Server table with the binary field. It can't use Filemaker databases.

My goal is to be able to run a command that will update binary column 'photo' based on the Base64 content in column photo_text.

I found this snippet which shows the results I want but I don't know how to write the binary result to the SQL table 'photo' field.

```
SELECT 
    volcards.photo_text, 
    CAST(N'' AS xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("volcards.photo_text"))', 'varbinary(max)') AS photo
FROM 
    volcards
```

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

my experience.. my solution is just use import function on FM.
to show the varbinary